# iMacro loop not working

Tags: loops, imacros

My aim is to download about 95000 publications with all related information into csv files from Web of Science. 
https://apps.webofknowledge.com/Search.do?product=WOS&SID=P2LaKOxW48huomyUkRR&search_mode=GeneralSearch&prID=3644417a-33e9-4e4d-b6f8-a346c7f1b109
I can download only 50 at one time, then have to click on 'next page', so to get all is quite a few downloads.

I have the following iMacro which is not looping.

Clicking on the dropdowns were not recorded by conventional methods, so I recorded most of the script by XY position. 
The script is not looping through automatically. It stops after loading the next 50 records.

What can be the issue? I am quite new to iMacros, so my apologies if this is something very basic.

```
SET !DATASOURCE "wos-thomson-inputpubs.csv"
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://apps.webofknowledge.com/summary.do?product=WOS&parentProduct=WOS&search_mode=GeneralSearch&parentQid=&qid=9&SID=T2soQIWLwg2JHnZOH27&&update_back2search_link_param=yes&page=1

WAIT SECONDS=2
CLICK X=721 Y=273
WAIT SECONDS=0.2
CLICK X=862 Y=395
WAIT SECONDS=0.2
CLICK X=616 Y=445
WAIT SECONDS=0.2
CLICK X=863 Y=445
WAIT SECONDS=0.2
CLICK X=618 Y=537
WAIT SECONDS=0.2
CLICK X=603 Y=488
WAIT SECONDS=0.2
CLICK X=687 Y=383
WAIT SECONDS=0.2
CLICK X=1219 Y=198
WAIT SECONDS=0.2
TAG POS=24 TYPE=I ATTR=TXT:
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the line with `URL GOTO=...` as follows:

```
URL GOTO=https://apps.webofknowledge.com/summary.do?product=WOS&parentProduct=WOS&search_mode=GeneralSearch&parentQid=&qid=9&SID=T2soQIWLwg2JHnZOH27&&update_back2search_link_param=yes&page={{!LOOP}}
```

Remove the command clicking the 'next page' and play the macro in loop mode.

*Note:* if you want to start, for example, from page #100, use this:

```
SET !LOOP 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If your all `url` in the `csv` file so there you need to change

```
GOTO={{LOOP}}
```

and run the iMacros with `Play (Loop)` option in iMacros extension **side bar**.